# System.Drawing.Graphics trim end of string?

Tags: c#, system.drawing, measurestring, system.drawing.graphics

While working on a text render algorithm, I stumbled across a strange behavior of the `Graphics.MeasureString()` method.

It seems like it internally trims the end of a string.

```
g.MeasureString("d", font).Width //is 13.289278
g.MeasureString("d ", font).Width //is 13.2892771
g.MeasureString(" d", font).Width //is 17.4858913
//font.Size = 11; font.FontFamily = "Arial";
```

Can someone explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformatflags%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) description of `MeasureTrailingSpaces` format flag:

> By default the boundary rectangle returned by the MeasureString method
>   excludes the space at the end of each line. Set this flag to include
>   that space in measurement.

So if you will provide this flag - results will be the same

```
var fmt = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces);
var x2 = g.MeasureString("d ", font, 0, fmt).Width;
var x3 = g.MeasureString(" d", font, 0, fmt).Width;
```